# Parsing a web page and extracting data

Tags: c#, web, web-scraping

I've been tasked with creating a web scraper (or screen scraper, however you want to look at it). I've found the HtmlAgilityPack but am wondering, given the following sample of HTML how would I extract things like phone number and such

```
<td valign="top" class="clsContent" style="width: 250px; padding-right: 21px">
    <span class=clsLabelB>Web: </span><a href='http://www.marriott.com/hotels/travel/sandm-san-diego-marriott-del-mar/' target=_blank>http://www.marriott.com/hotels/travel/sandm-san-diego-marriott-del-mar/</a><br />
    <div style='padding-top:7px'>
        <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
            <tr>
                <td valign=top class=clsLabelB nowrap>Phone:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top>+1 858-523-1700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign=top class=clsLabelB nowrap>Fax:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top>+1 858-523-1355</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign=top class=clsLabelB nowrap>Toll Free:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td valign=top>800-228-9290</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <p><span class=clsLabelB>Chain: </span><a href='/Hotels/Companies/Marriott-International'>Marriott International</a><br />
    <span class=clsLabelB>Chain Website: </span><a href='http://www.marriott.com' target=_blank>http://www.marriott.com</a>
    <p><span class=clsLabelB>Description: </span>Contemporary high-rise hotel - Convenient to area companies, beaches, golf, shopping, San Diego Zoo and Sea World.<br />
    <div style='padding-top:7px'>
        <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
            <tr>
                <td valign=top class=clsLabelB width=170px nowrap>Year Renovated:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top>2003</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style='padding-top:7px'>
        <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
            <tr>
                <td valign=top class=clsLabelB width=170px nowrap>Check in Time:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top>4:00 PM</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign=top class=clsLabelB width=170px nowrap>Check out Time:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>  
                <td valign=top>12:00 PM</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign=top class=clsLabelB width=170px nowrap>Number of Floors:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top>11</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign=top class=clsLabelB width=170px nowrap>Total Number of Rooms:&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top>284</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</td>
```

At this time I've got no sample code to show as I'm completely stuck on this one, any help or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try like this, this is a sample code

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load("file.html");
    string phone_number = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//td[contains(text(), 'Phone')]//following-sibling::td[1]"]).InnerText
```